# Chrome not prompting windows auth login until devtools opened

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, http, windows-authentication

I have a react app that is needing to authenticate against a windows auth server. I am achieving this by hitting an endpoint to get my user details, with the credentials: include header. From my understanding, this should trigger the login prompt on chrome. However the prompt does not show until I either:

- Hard refresh the page
- Open devtools

Because it doesn't prompt a logon, the app shows as empty, because I'm returning null if its not authenticated.

How can I get chrome to actually prompt for logon details in the normal app view?

*App.tsx*

```
export const App: React.FC = () => {
  const { isAuthenticated, login } = useAuth();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isAuthenticated) {
      login();
    }
  }, [isAuthenticated, login]);

  if (!isAuthenticated) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div>App Content</div>
  );
};
```

*AuthProvider.tsx*

```
export const AuthProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const [user, setUser] = useState<IUserDetail>();

  const login = useCallback(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    UserApi.getMe()
      .then(({ data }) => setUser(data))
      .finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
  }, []);

  const logout = useCallback(() => {
    setUser(undefined);
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        user,
        isAuthenticated: Boolean(user),
        isLoading,
        login,
        logout,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);
```

*UserApi.ts*

```
export const getMe = () => {
  return axios.get<IUserDetail>("/api/users/me");
};
```

*Axios interceptor logic, which sets the credentials header for every request*

```
axios.interceptors.request.use((request) => {
  request.headers["credentials"] = "include";

  return request;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a fundamental misunderstanding. The authentication happens when the website is downloaded from the server - not when I make an API request.

The reason for why I wasn't getting the auth prompt was because I had a service worker that cached the files, so they weren't being requested from the server, thus no auth prompt.